# Not using newer kernel version - Any real problems with it?

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I have been searching for the answer of this question, but I couldn't find.

I know I can upgrade the kernel version to the newer one, but it seems that a lot of people had problems after installing it. So, I would prefer to stay with this version, that is working perfectly.

But, even if I have an older version of the kernel (3.13), I will receive updates (security or not) for this version? Or I have to upgrade in order to continue receiving updates for it?

Thank you guys for helping me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`3.13` is the kernel version for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and will be supported until April 2019.  Ubuntu 14.04.2 comes with `3.16` which only has an 18 month support from Feb 2015.  So, you shouldn't have any problems staying with kernel `3.13`.

[image]